# How to handle identity/ autoincrement columns when writing to Exasol DB?

Tags: python, pandas, exasol

I have an Exasol table with an autoincrement primary key and want to fill it using import_from_pandas from pyexasol.

By importing to exasol table I have to leave the RKEY out since Exasol auto increments it. But leaving rkey empty or not creating the rkey column in pandas at all doesn’t work for me.

I went through pandas.to_csv and it doesn’t seem to have an option to leave out columns when writing to csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyexasol

score = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['rkey','score'])
score['score'] = list(range(10))
conn = pyexasol.connect(dsn=dsn,user=user, password=pw,compression=True)
conn.import_from_pandas(score,(schema, table))
```

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Exasol does not behave identity columns as a constraint, I mean you can insert multiple values, or insert explicit values into an identity column on an Exasol table. So it seems to be quite flexible for a developer

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works.

```
conn.import_from_pandas(score,(schema, table),import_params=    {'columns':list(score.columns)})
```